# How to data specific data from json file in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm new to angularjs and I'm trying to retrieve json data from a json file. But i'm unable to do it.

This was my approach in the controller:

```
.controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://feeds.citibikenyc.com/stations/stations.json').
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           $scope.data = data;
           alert(data);
    }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
}]);
```

I want to save specific values to the scope. How can I do this? In the alert it shows: [object Object].

How can I access each value inside this json file?

Thanks.

Comment: do `console.log(data.stationBeanList)` also write http service in a different service file and call in contoller, do the stuff in `then` block

Comment: then i get many [object Object] s.. i think it's equal to the number of objects i have in this json

Comment: you can expand them in your console. right?

Comment: yes. when i use it like " data.stationBeanList[0].id " i can access the id of first record. but i want to get all the id values at once.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(data)`  will show you data.

Comment: can i use ng-repeat to get what i want?

Comment: @GaveenSalinda did you checked the answer. It will work according to your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var item in data.stationBeanList){
   alert(item.id);
}
```

will get you all ids of list **OR** you can push to array this way

```
var ids = [];
for(var item in data.stationBeanList){
   ids.push(item.id);
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list =  data.stationBeanList;

var listId = list.map( function (object) {
     return object.id;
});
```

By this you'll get all your id's in a single array `listId`